# What is Braggart in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am watching the movie *Das Boot* in German with English Subtitles, but there is one part where the captain says braggart (based on subtitles) in German. I couldn't really hear what he said, but it sounded like

> "Mauhelden".

I couldn't find anything when I googled "**Mauhelden**" and didn't correct it to the right word. If I specifically translate "*braggart*" to German, I get "*Prahler/Angeber*". What is the word he used and where does it come from (as in what region of Germany)?

Comment: The dictionary BEOLINGUS gives *Maulheld* as [translation of *braggart*](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/?query=braggart), and [dict.cc, too](https://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/braggart.html). Wiktionary has an [entry for *Maulheld*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Maulheld), and [DWDS, too](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Maulheld).

Comment: You heared "Maulhelden" and as @unor mentioned this word is translated to braggart and has the meanings you found out.

Comment: And should you wonder, *Maulheld* is literally *yap hero*.

Comment: *Maulheld*, *Angeber* or *Aufschneider* would be appropriate translations.

Comment: I saw someone voted to close this question due to being off-topic (“GermanSE is not a replacement for general references”), and initially I did not agree with that, because it may be difficult to find a word if you do not know its spelling, particularly if one of the first letters is wrong or missing. However, google.de finds the correct term, google.com also does (still on the first page of the list of results) and duden.de suggests Maulheldentum. There’s no difficulty after all, hence I agree to the close vote.

Comment: dict.leo.org is a good reference, and recognises plural forms like *Maulhelden*

Comment: @PiedPiper Well, the problem seems to have been that the OP understood and searched Mauhelden (without the first lowercase „L“), and therefor didn’t find the term Maulhelden. The other commentators seem to overlook that. Anyway, the question’s closed now.

Comment: @Philipp Sorry, I missed the missing "l". Both words look almost the same to me. Anyway the question has been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Maulhelden" - any plural plural form of ["Maulheld"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maulheld) or any singular except Nominativ.
Literally translated: "hero of/by her/his mouth".
So, "braggart(s)" indeed.

Comment: is it plural or accusative (or a different case)?